# Problems with logging setup in bootstrapped Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to do simple file logging config in pyramid, with python 2.7.2 and pyramid 1.2.3

It isn't working at all how I expected.  It looks like even though i'm bootstrapping into pyramid, it isn't loading the right logs.  Specific problems below within test.py:

test.py

```
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
env = bootstrap('../test.ini')

import logging
logging.basicConfig()  #this apparently makes no difference
log=logging.getLogger('root') #same thing if I do getLogger(__name__) - it doesn't find the proj one.
print log.handlers
>>> []
```

That's weird!  no handlers?  Apparently it's not the log I am thinking of.

```
print log

>>> logging.Logger
```

shouldn't it be a RootLogger?

```
print log.parent

>>> [<logging.RootLogger>]
```

hmm so the parent of getLogger('root') is the real RootLogger?  let's see what its handlers are:

```
print log.parent.handlers

>>> [<logging.StreamHandler>]
```

that's weird.

test.ini:

```
[app:proj]
use = egg:proj
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+mysqldb://proj_staging:pw@localhost/proj_staging?charset=utf8
# This apparently helps avoid mysql gone away errors
sqlalchemy.pool_recycle = 3600

[pipeline:main]
pipeline = proj

[loggers]
keys = root, proj

[handlers]
keys = console, file

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = file
qualname=root

[logger_proj]
level = DEBUG
handlers = 
qualname = proj

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[handler_file]
class = FileHandler
args=('../logs/proj.log','a')
formatter = generic
level = INFO

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pyramid doesn't load the logging configuration when bootstrapping. If you want to make an argument that it should, please open a ticket at https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues

Regardless, it's pretty simple to load the logging information yourself:

```
import logging
import logging.config
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
logging.config.fileConfig('../test.ini')
env = bootstrap('../test.ini')

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.debug('foo')
```

Comment: ah, that's great.  I had just assumed it would load logging along with all the other stuff.